# use cactus and junit 4 at the same

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Is it possible to use cactus and Junit 4 at the same time? 
Because I know that current cactus release is based on Junit 3.8. 
Cactus looks like hasn't been maintained for a long time,doesn't even support annotation, is there any better framework to replace cactus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia has a link to a [workaround](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CACTUS-252).  Note that a JUnit 4 suite can run JUnit 3.8 tests.  This means you can keep your Cactus tests as JUnit 3.8 and your other tests as JUnit 4.